# Hibernate trying to delete foreign key row in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to delete an entity from the database using the crudRepository delete action in spring hibernate/jpa. The entity (user) has a `@OnetoMany` relationship with an other entity (organisation). When deleting the user it also attempts to delete the row corresponding to the foreign key in the organisation table at which point an error is thrown.

I DO NOT want to delete the row in the organisation table, and only want to delete the user `userRepository.delete(createdUser);`. Can anyone tell me why this is not working as expected?

**User.java**

```
/**
 * The user's organisation
 */
@NotNull
@SerializedName("organisation")
@Expose
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id")
private Organisation organisation;
```

**Organisation.java**

```
/**
 * The organisation's domain name
 */
@NotNull
private String domainName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "organisation")
private Set<User> users;
```

**UserServiceTest**

```
@Test
public void create_SaveUserNewEntryToDatabase_ShouldReturnSingleUser() throws UserExistsException {
    long numberOfDbEntries = userRepository.count();
    User newUser = new User("jane@ibmtest.com", "Jane", "Claire", "Jones", new Long(98765), new Long(54321));
    User createdUser = userService.create(newUser);

    assertNotNull(createdUser);
    assertEquals(numberOfDbEntries+1, userRepository.count());
    assertEquals(createdUser.getFirstName(), "Jane");
    assertEquals(createdUser.getMiddleName(), "Claire");
    assertEquals(createdUser.getLastName(), "Jones");
    assertEquals(createdUser.getEmail(), "jane@ibmtest.com");
    assertEquals(createdUser.getOrganisation(), new Long(98765));
    assertEquals(createdUser.getUserRole(), new Long(54321));

    userRepository.delete(createdUser);  <------
    assertEquals(numberOfDbEntries, userRepository.count());
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitException: Exception processing table name='user'
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:232)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`watchmaker_db`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `FK_t2c7mdyen6pg5d1hpwyw6ox4e` FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.SimplePreparedStatement.addBatch(SimplePreparedStatement.java:80)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.AutomaticPreparedBatchStatement.addBatch(AutomaticPreparedBatchStatement.java:70)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:214)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: The exception is a DBUnit exception, thrown from a setup method. It's not thrown by your test method.

Comment: But it is caused by

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`watchmaker_db`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `FK_t2c7mdyen6pg5d1hpwyw6ox4e` FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`id`))

Comment: I don't think the exception is caused by the problem you describe. Why don't you activate SQL logging in the hibernate configuration, and see which SQL statements are effectively executed by Hibernate in your test?

Comment: caused by DBUnit.beforeTestMethod ... so its in setup, not in a test. Stack trace can't be clearer, so look at the log what SQL is issued by your setup().

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would have expected the test to work because you are using a `foreign key`. I worked when I tried it with HSQLDB, which also has constraints, so I'm not sure what's going on there. Try it with the `Organization` POJO directly. Remove the `User` from it and resave the `Organization`.

```
Organization o =organizationRepository.findAll().iterator().next();
o.getUsers().remove(0);
organizationRepository.save(o);
```

EDIT: Maybe you have some manual SQL inserts in your setup that's failing before you get to your test.

Comment: This solution is fine but when you add organisation again, it will add the organisation at the end of table, which will disrupt the sequence. What to do in that case ?